# Grok equivalent for ZCML's "require" directive

Tags: plone, zope, grok, zcml

I'm writing an add-view adapter and want to restrict its use to a specific permission.

In ZCML I can do the following:

```
<class class=".add.AddView">
    <require
        permission="cmf.AddPortalContent"
        interface="zope.publisher.interfaces.browser.IBrowserPage"
        />
</class>
```

Is there a grok equivalent way of doing this?

Simply using *grok.require* doesn't work.

My adapter looks like this:

```
class AddForm(grok.MultiAdapter, add.AddView):
    grok.adapts(IFolderish, IThemeSpecific, IDynamicViewTypeInformation)
    grok.name('addATDocument')
    grok.provides(IBrowserPage)
    grok.require('cmf.AddPortalContent')
```

But without the ZCML snippet, I can anonymously render the add view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the package grokcore.security 1.5

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/grokcore.security#defining-permissions